# Как сделать ломаный фон?

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно срезать фон вверху и внизу таким образом? Благодарю!

```css
p {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
}

.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #ffffff url(http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/krasota_prirody/les_hvoyniy_foto_02.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="cover"></div>
<p></p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `clip-path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Первый вариант** `CSS` — `clip-path`:

```css
p {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
}

.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #ffffff url(http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/krasota_prirody/les_hvoyniy_foto_02.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 50% 6%, 80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 18%, 80% 18%, 50% 24%, 20% 18%, 0 18%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 50% 6%, 80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 18%, 80% 18%, 50% 24%, 20% 18%, 0 18%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div class="cover"></div>
<p></p>
```

**Второй вариант** `SVG` — `clipPath`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <polygon points="0,0 50,0 150,10 250,0 300,0 300,50 250,50 150,60 50,50 0,50"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/400/300/any" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @LADYX, Добавил ещё один вариант. Используется Polygon, которому задаются точки `X` & `Y`

Comment: @LADYX, был рад помочь=)